# Spark + Cassandra Integration

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Cassandra-3.7 version and Spark-1.6.2 version on a Hadoop-2.7.2 version. I have been trying to integrate Cassandra with Spark. For the purpose, following the instructions in http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/kindling-an-introduction-to-spark-with-cassandra/.

As per the instructions, I cloned the spark-cassandra-connector project:

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector
```

Once the project is cloned, I changed my working directory to spark-cassandra-connector:

```
cd spark-cassandra-connector/
```

In the spark-cassandra-connector directory, I gave the following command to build the connector:

```
./sbt/sbt assembly
```

But the build is failing with the following errors:

```
[error] 4 not found
[error]   /.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
[error]   /.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[error]   /.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[error]   /.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

The entire output is as follows:

```
Attempting to fetch sbt
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.9.jar
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/project
[info] Updating {file:/usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/project/}spark-cassandra-connector-build...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jgit#org.eclipse.jgit.archive;3.7.0.201502260915-r [info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-c5d1b95fdcc1e1007740ffbecf4eb07[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * net.virtual-void:sbt-dependency-graph:0.7.4 -> 0.8.2
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources to /usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] there were 4 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
Using releases: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2 for releases
Using snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots for snapshots

  Scala: 2.10.6 [To build against Scala 2.11 use '-Dscala-2.11=true']
  Scala Binary: 2.10
  Java: target=1.7 user=1.8.0_77
  Cassandra version for testing: 3.0.2 [can be overridden by specifying '-Dtest.cassandra.version=<version>']

[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/)
[warn] Credentials file /.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Formatting 46 Scala sources {file:/usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/}spark-cassandra-connector(test) ...
[info] Formatting 158 Scala sources {file:/usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/}spark-cassandra-connector(compile) ...
[warn] Credentials file /.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Updating com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.6.0-20-g4edacfb
[info] Reformatted 44 Scala sources {file:/usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/}spark-cassandra-connector(test).
[info] Resolved com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.6.0-20-g4edacfb dependencies
[info] Fetching artifacts of com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.6.0-20-g4edacfb
[info] Reformatted 143 Scala sources {file:/usr/local/spark-cassandra-connector/}spark-cassandra-connector(compile).
[info] Fetched artifacts of com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.6.0-20-g4edacfb
[error] 4 not found
[error]   /.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
[error]   /.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[error]   /.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
[error]  /.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
java.lang.Exception: Encountered 4 errors (see above messages)
    at coursier.Tasks$$anonfun$updateTask$1.coursier$Tasks$$anonfun$$report$1(Tasks.scala:710)
    at coursier.Tasks$$anonfun$updateTask$1$$anonfun$apply$49.apply(Tasks.scala:748)
    at coursier.Tasks$$anonfun$updateTask$1$$anonfun$apply$49.apply(Tasks.scala:748)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:189)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:91)
    at coursier.Tasks$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Tasks.scala:741)
    at coursier.Tasks$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Tasks.scala:517)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (spark-cassandra-connector/*:update) java.lang.Exception: Encountered 4 errors (see above messages)
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 19-Jul-2016 5:03:12 AM
```

What am I doing wrong? Could someone help?

Answer (score 3):

This is may because your m2 directory may have different version of libraries and hence they are not downloaded just delete the libraries from m2 and then try once again

Comment: This fixed the error, just deleted everything inside ~/.m2, thank you!